# how to implement Java websocket client in java fx and backend server is tomcat .?

Tags: java, websocket

i want to develop websocket application in java where client side is java fx. and server is tomcat can any one help me with example.
I cant able to do it with websocket servlet.  it runs perfectly with javascript ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to look for a client-side implementation of JSR356. See [here](https://www.openshift.com/blogs/how-to-build-java-websocket-applications-using-the-jsr-356-api), [here](http://aredko.blogspot.de/2013/11/java-websockets-jsr-356-on-jetty-91.html) and [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jsr356-1937161.html). Doing so, essentially, a client is marked with the `@ClientEndpoint` annotator.

Comment: It must be run on jetty.  I m using tomcat..  now what to do can u help me out?

Comment: Tomcat implements JSR356: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/web-socket-howto.html

Comment: I already read it.  But I m using Tomcat 8.0. Websocket Api is removed in 8.0. Now What to do??  Please Help me.. By the way Thanks.

Comment: Did you really read it? The _proprietory_ API is removed in 8.0, not the new JSR356 API.